# Como comparar 2 Arrays com Assert.Equals?

Tags: c#, array, tdd

Preciso comparar dois arrays no `Assert.Equals`.

Quando eu testo o método na raça ele está certo mas no teste não passa.

***Código:***

```
public void SeparaStringTest() {
 RecebeComando recebecomando = new RecebeComando();
 string[] StringSeparada = {
  "A",
  "A",
  "B"
 };

 Assert.Equals(recebecomando.SeparaString("AAB"), StringSeparada);
 Assert.Equals(recebecomando.SeparaString("A A B"), StringSeparada);
 Assert.Equals(recebecomando.SeparaString("A-A-B"), StringSeparada);
}

public string[] SeparaString(string palavra) {
 palavra = palavra.Replace("-", "");
 palavra = palavra.Replace(" ", "");

 var comando = new string[palavra.Length];

 for (int i = 0; i < comando.Length; i++) {
  comando[i] = palavra[i].ToString();
 }
 return comando;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

O comando `Assert.AreEqual` compara como uma referência, para que você possa comparar arrays ou listas, você deve usar o `CollectionAssert.AreEqual`

```
public void SeparaStringTest()
{
    RecebeComando recebecomando = new RecebeComando();
    string[] StringSeparada = { "A", "A", "B" };

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(recebecomando.SeparaString("AAB"), StringSeparada);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(recebecomando.SeparaString("A A B"), StringSeparada);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(recebecomando.SeparaString("A-A-B"), StringSeparada);
}
```

Vide documentação da Microsoft:

Assert.AreEqual: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.areequal.aspx

CollectionAssert.AreEqual: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms243763.aspx

Comment: @gabriel-rodrigues Na sua pergunta você tambem está utilizando o método errado na comparação (conforme dito pelo JBueno) não é Assert.Equals e sim Assert.AreEquals, mais de toda forma deve ser utilizado o CollectionAssert para coleções.

Answer (score 5):

Primeiro tem um erro aí, `Assert.Equals` tem o mesmo comportamento do método `Equals` de `object`, ou seja, este método verifica se duas variáveis apontam para a mesma referência.

Provavelmente você quer usar o método `Assert.AreEqual`, este vai comparar item por item dos arrays e verificar seus valores.

Eu também aproveitei e fiz uma modificação pra deixar o método `SeparaString` um pouco mais simples.

```
public static string[] SeparaString(string palavra, char? separador)
{
    string[] comando;

    if(separador == null)
        comando = palavra.ToCharArray().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
    else
        comando = palavra.Split((char)separador);

    return comando;
}
```

O uso seria

```
SeparaString("AAB", null);
SeparaString("AAB", '-');
SeparaString("AAB", ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui resolver, de fato precisei mudar para Assert.AreEqual o teste ficou assim:

```
public void SeparaStringTest()
{
    RecebeComando recebecomando = new RecebeComando();           
    string[] retornoDoMétodo = recebecomando.SeparaString("AAB");
    Assert.AreEqual(retornoDoMétodo.Length, 3);
    Assert.AreEqual(retornoDoMétodo[0], "A");
    Assert.AreEqual(retornoDoMétodo[1], "A");
    Assert.AreEqual(retornoDoMétodo[2], "B");
}
```

Comment: Ao invés de criar uma resposta, você pode comentar na resposta que mais te ajudou e marcá-la como correta. É uma forma de agradecer quem escreveu a resposta e também deixar registrado que aquela foi a que mais te atendeu.

Comment: Essa implementação que você fez é muito engessada e pouco produtiva, o CollectionAssert.AreEqual faz o trabalho sujo pra você e trabalha com qualquer collection, ou seja, se você for comparar outro Array com mais itens, você não precisará incluir mais nada no código. Vou editar minha resposta incluindo um exemplo do que você deverá implementar.